# How to show $X_n$ converges in distribution to U(0,1)

Tags: distributions, inference

Assuming $X_n$ has a discrete distribution on the set $\{\frac{1}{n}\frac{2}{n},...,\frac{n-1}{n},1\}$. We want to show that $X_n \xrightarrow{D}U(0,1)$.

I tried to find the CDF of $X_n$ to start, but I unsure how to do this. If I find $\lim_{n\to\infty}F_{X_N}$ and then compute the partial derivative with respect to $t$ and show this is equivalent to $U(0,1)$ I think I will be done. But I don't know how to find the CDF.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One can inspect the CDF's. The CDF's of $X_n$ is simply
$$
F_n(x) = \frac{[xn]}{n}, \; 0 \leq x \leq 1
$$
where $[y]$ is the integer part of a real number $y$. The graph of $F_n$ looks like a staircase going from $0$ to $1$ in steps of $\frac{1}{n}$. As $n\rightarrow \infty$, the step size $\frac{1}{n} \rightarrow 0$, and
$$
F_n(x) \rightarrow F(x), \; 0 \leq x \leq 1
$$
which is the CDF of the uniform distribution.

*"...compute the partial derivative with respect to t..."*---there is no differentiation involved.

Another easy answer is to use the actual [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_measures#Weak_convergence_of_measures) of convergence in distribution:
$X_n$ convergence in distribution to $X$ if, for all continuous bounded function $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$
$$
E[ f(X_n) ] \rightarrow E[f(X)].
$$
In your case,
$$
E[ f(X_n) ] = \sum_{i=1}^n f(\frac{i}{n})\frac{1}{n},
$$
which, by definition of the Riemann integral, converges to $\int_0^1 f(t) dt = E[f(X)]$, where $X$ is distributed uniformly on $[0,1]$.